# Display application controls in English when OS is non-English

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

My goal is to display the control DateTimePicker and MonthCalender from VS2010 in English when my Windows 7 is in Norwegian.

My problem is that I don't know how to make the date to display in English when my computers settings is not in English.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SetThreadLocale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374051%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to override locale setting of your application.

Comment: Be sure to read the remark section to see whether any of the restrictions apply to you